# Al instalar certificados a mi web por certbot, la web no se ve

Tags: servidor, ssl

Tengo un servidor montadon en una orangepi zero, anda todo perfecto hasta que quiero ponerle certificados a mi web con el comando certbot luego de instalar los sertificados la web se redirecciona pero me aparece

No se puede acceder a este sitioprogramadorfullstack.ar rechazó la conexión.
Intenta:

Comprobar la conexión.
Comprobar el proxy y el firewall.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

el comando que uso es :

certbot --authenticator webroot -w /var/www/html -d dominio.com,www.dominio.com --installer apache

Comment: y se llama asi dominio.com?

Comment: Recuerda que https usa el puerto 443, revisa el cortafuegos.

Comment: No dominio.com es un ejemplo es el metodo que uso para instalar el certificado, era el pueto seguramente.